# Is the vahana (mount) of Lord Ganesha a shrew or a mouse?

Tags: ganesha, animals, vahana

Is the vahana (mount) of Lord Ganesha a shrew or a mouse?

The internet is ambiguous about this. Some sources say that `mooshika` is a shrew [1](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Book_University_Journal/9OoDAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=shrew%20) while others say that it is a mouse [2](https://books.google.com/books?id=H5DjAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=mouse); both of which are very different animals.

Answer (score 1):

Ganesha in scripture rides on the mouse, the word 'shrew' is never mentioned in that context.

I won't quote every instance of it being mentioned, but here are two:

> Śacī said :-- “Indra has got for his vehicles the horse Uccaiśravā, the Airāvata elephant and the chariot; Vāsudeva has got vehicle Garuḍa; Yama has got his buffalo; Śaṅkara his Bull; Brahmā his Swan; Kartika has got his peacock and **Ganeśa has got his mouse**.
>
> ---
>
> [[Devi Bhagavata Purana]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57234.html)

and

> 13. Then **Śumbha and Gaṇeśa seated respectively in a chariot and on a mouse** fought each other with volleys of arrows.
> 14. Gaṇeśa hit Śumbha in his chest with an arrow and felled his charioteer with three arrows on the ground.
> 15. Then the infuriated Śumbha covered Gaṇeśa with a shower of arrows. Hitting the mouse with three arrows he roared like thunder.
> 16. The mouse pierced by the arrows, shook with acute pain. Gaṇeśa was thrown off (his vehicle) and he became a foot soldier (as it were).
> 17. Then Gaṇeśa hit Śumbha in his chest with his axe and felled him to the ground. **Thereafter he mounted his mouse again.**
>
> ---
>
> [[Shiva Purana]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226162.html)
>
> atha śuṃbho gaṇeśaśca ratha**mūṣaka** vāhanau |
> yudhyamānau śaravrātaiḥ parasparamavidhyatām || 13 ||
>
> tato lambodaraśśuṃbhaṃ hatvā paraśunā hṛdi |
> apātayattadā bhūmau **mūṣakaṃ** cāruroha saḥ || 17 ||

As we see, the original Sanskrit version of the Shiva Purana does indeed use the word '*mūṣaka*', which, as a [Sanskrit dictionary will tell you](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=musaka&dir=au), means 'mouse.'

Comment: In Tamil folklore his vahana is the மூஞ்சுறு or Mole Rat.  folklore also says that is why cats don't eat them although they are very slow @cdr

Comment: @SK - interesting, though I guess it can't be added here because it's unlikely to be written in scripture.

Comment: Added some citations to texts that cause the confusion.

Comment: What is the term that is used in scripture to describe the vaahana? It is possible that over the time, the meaning has been lost and since a mouse is more common than a shrew, the accepted translation may have become different.

Comment: @proteus - I added some information that addresses your comment; the original term is, in fact, '_mūṣaka_'.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of Mushaka can be search in [Sanskrit to English dictionary](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=mUSaka&dir=se) or in [Google Translator](https://translate.google.co.in/?sl=sa&tl=en&text=%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%95&op=translate) respectively.

It's mostly translated as Mouse or Rat.

I hope this clarifies your queries.

Comment: Added some citations to texts that cause the confusion.

Comment: See it was translated by someone who didn't know which meaning to use. On Sanskrit varaha means both bull and boar. Yes shrew looks like a mouse only, but its smaller than a mouse with pointed nose n small eyes.